# Syntax error in python for some reason I do not know

Tags: python, syntax-error

I was running a simple code of someone else and getting this error I do not understand why it is showing syntax error

```
oddcounter = 0 
total = 0 
for i in range(0, 10, 1):     
   number =int(input("please enter the number:")     
   if number%2 != 0:
      total = total + 1     
      oddcounter = oddcounter + 1       
      

average = total/oddcounter 
print("the total of the odd numbers is", total, "and their average is", average)
```

I am getting following error

[image]

Why it is showing syntax error?

Comment: You're missing a right parenthesis on the line before this (`number = ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int is not closed with ‘)’. Please close it to wipe this error.